# codeigniter-external java scriptfile not working?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

codeigniter-external java scriptfile not working?
in my view file:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/getquestion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a onclick="getQuestion()" style="width: 280px; height: 540px; padding-top: 3px;" class="btn btn-primary" id="HyperLink">Start</a>
```

getquestion.js:

```
function getquestion() {
    $.get("http://localhost/n/saq/saq/index.php/quizs/getquestion", function (resp) {
        if (resp != null) {
            $("#question").html(resp);
            $("#loading").html("");
        }
    })
}
```

when i click start button not showing any thing,
but when i navigate to url `http://localhost/n/saq/saq/index.php/quizs/getquestion` its working. pls help me

Comment: check your onclick event function name..your function name is  getquestion() and you're using like  getQuestion()...change tht first....

Comment: try add `alert('yay');` before `$.get ...` script. If "yay" appear, then the problem is in your `$.get` script. If even "yay" not appear, maybe you have wrong `src` of the .js file

Answer (score 0):

Which folder you put your .js at?
Usually .js files are take places in assets/js folder, so you'll need:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/getquestion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or you can ... (more neat)

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/getquestion.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> **Just for information considering this is 2017 already**
>
> - HTML5 don't need us to include the type attribute in `<script>` tag
> - PHP echo have a shorthand, instead of `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`, you just need `<?= base_url() ?>`
>
> So you may write just like this:
>
> ```
> <script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/js/getquestion.js"></script>
> ```
>
> ... and you must include `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the first line of your pages

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/getquestion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <a  onclick="getquestion()" style="width: 280px; height: 540px; padding-top: 3px;" class="btn btn-primary" id="HyperLink">Start</a>
     <p id="question"></p>
    </body>
```

js code,

```
function getquestion() {
            $.get(<?php echo base_url("index.php/getquestions"),function(result){
            if(result != null) {
             //alert(result);
             document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=result;
             }
      });
}
```